# SSRS expression: If string then associated date field

Tags: reporting-services, expression, iif

I tried all kinds of variations of the following in my ssrs expression:

```
 =iif(Fields!varchar.Value = "ABC20", Fields!StartDate.Value,Nothing)
```

It either yields the False clause, the first date field, or it shows as #Error when debugging.

The data type of StartDate is `Date (Format= yyyy-mm-dd)`. Your help in resolving this is much appreciated.

Comment: What does the error message say? You say *First Date Field* - are you expecting a list of dates? It sounds like you're using the expression in a text box and not a table.

Comment: Apologies for being inaccurate - I am not expecting a list of dates. It yields the date (e.g. 2020-01-01) for the first (top most) field in the varchar column. That's what was meant with First Date Field. There is no deployment error message, just the #Error in the Report Server view. Yes, I am using the expression in a text box.Let me know if this is helpful, or if you need additional information.

Comment: Does the error happen when previewing in Visual Studio? Does the error description show up in Error List?

Comment: Figured it out. I used the following: Format(Max(iif(Fields!varchar.Value = "ABC20",
             CDate(Fields!StartDate.Value),Nothing)),"MM/dd/yyyy")